# Get all data from different tables in a SQLite database in Node.js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sqlite

Is it a way to get all data from a database?

So far I accomplished to get all data from a table:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  db.serialize(function () {
    db.all('SELECT id, name, surname FROM Table1', function (
      err,
      rows
    ) {
      return res.send(rows);
    });
  });

  db.close();
});
```

but if there are more tables, `Table1`, `Table2` and `Table3` for example.

Trying to put all the queries in the db.all call doesn't seem to work.

```
 router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
      db.serialize(function () {
        db.all('SELECT id, name, surname FROM Table1, SELECT date, city FROM Table2, SELECT person, year FROM Table3', function (
          err,
          rows
        ) {
          return res.send(rows);
        });
      });
    
      db.close();
    });
```

**UPDATE**

these are the tables, how can I get all their data and send it into front-end? that's what I want to do.

I would rather want to have them like separate tables in the front-end where the call is fetched like this:

```
callAPI() {
    fetch('http://localhost:9000/testAPI')
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then((res) => this.setState({ apiResponse: res }));
  }
```

is there a way to send all these tables?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: So you can nest multiple db.all calls, putting the next one in the callback `function(){}` portion of the previous.  Your'e doing that correctly if your code keeps indenting to the right.  Call res.send only in the last one... That only helps if you have only a few tables and know how the queries in advance. If you want to ask the database for the table list, and then act on it, it gets more complex.  Specifically, you need a way to iterate asynchronously.  You can do that and avoid nesting callbacks using node's `async` library or perhaps `Promise.all` if your framework understands promises.

Comment: I'm using Node.js so I guess `Promise.all` works fine. I updated the question with the tables, I don't understand why isn't it working. Sending one table is working fine but sending them all doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Provided that all your tables have the same columns or at-least the output can be aliased into same column names (maybe put nulls if the column is not in one of the tables), you can make use of `UNION`

eg:

```
SELECT id, name FROM table1 
 UNION 
   SELECT id, name FROM table2
 UNION 
   SELECT myid as id, test as name FROM table3
```

This way you can append all such tables into a single output table. Also if you want it to aggregate through code, you can use the below query to get all table names and work with each table:

```
SELECT name FROM my_db.sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
```

Comment: just updated the question, the tables do not have the same column names. I've tried with `UNION` and `UNION ALL` but it doesn't return any data

Comment: You will have to use alias names for your column outputs, use `AS` to make sure that the column names are some for each table

Comment: I would recommend going for the second approach if the tables are completely different.
Btw your 700th goal was awesome ! :)

Comment: Look at table3 of my example query

Comment: so I did it like this:` 'SELECT name FROM ocs_athletes.sqlite_master WHERE type="table"',` , the name of my db is `ocs_athletes`. is it wrong? because it still doesn't show anything

Comment: This query will return the name of all tables in your db. Try to run this query from a db viewer and see the results. Once you have the table name list. Iterate over the table list and run the query for each table

Comment: the problem is that it doesn't return anything at the moment.

Comment: I just ran the query in an dummy sqlite db and I got the table names. Are you running the some sqlite browser or from js
`SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type="table"`

Comment: I'm running it in node.js

Comment: Try and see it running in a db browser

Comment: it worked like this: SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type="table". to get the table names

Comment: Cool, now from the result set iterate over each table name and fetch data, maybe use `Promise.all`

Comment: @LeoMessi did it work for you ? If so, can you accept my answer ?

Comment: I can get the names of the tables but not the data. I'm trying to do it now with Promise.all

Comment: For each table you will have to query the data separately. Try doing it separately without `Promise.all` first and then later add them to promise all

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do